# How can I exclude products whose variations have certain meta when using WooCommerce Product Archive loop?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been studying wp_query and the forums extensively, but I haven't yet found the gem I'm looking for.

When viewing a products archive page, pulled from WooCommerce's archive-product.php, I need to exclude products that have **any** variations with post meta key "variation_my_template" set to string "0" **or** meta key "variation_my_template" is unset.

I've been messing with the 'woocommerce_product_query' action, which seems to be a good place to start.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_products_without_templates');
function hide_products_without_templates($q){
  $meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');
  $meta_query[] = [
    'key' => 'variation_my_template',
    'value' => '0',
    'compare' => '!='
  ];
  $q->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
}
```

The problem is that this is merely checking to see if the key of the **parent** products, not their variations. I need to exclude the products which have ANY variations that have the variation_my_template meta set to "0" or unset.

Any direction as to the best way to get and check the variations and then exclude their parents upon matching my criteria would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by just running another query and using that to exclude certain posts from the original/main query.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_products_without_templates');
function hide_products_without_templates($q){
        $parentsToExclude = $q->get('post__not_in');

        $query = new WP_Query ([
            'post_type' => 'product_variation',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query'    => [
                'relation' => 'OR',
                [
                    'key' => 'variable_my_template',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    'fields'    => 'slug',
                ],
                [
                    'key' => 'variable_my_template',
                    'value' => '',
                    'fields'    => 'slug',
                    'type'  => 'string',
                ],
                [
                    'key' => 'variable_my_template',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'fields'    => 'slug',
                    'type'  => 'NUMERIC',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        $results = array();
        if($query->have_posts()){
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->next_post();
                $results[] = $query->post;
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        wp_reset_query();
        foreach( $results as $product) {
            $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($product->ID);
            if(!in_array($parent_id,$parentsToExclude)) $parentsToExclude[] = $parent_id;
        }
        error_log('POSTS:');
        error_log(print_r($parentsToExclude,true));
        $q->set('post__not_in',$parentsToExclude);
}
```